# Java nio connection is creating multiple socket level connections, Why?

Tags: java, io, nio

I have written a simple java nio program like the below

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


    InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",1001);
    Selector incomingMessageSelector = Selector.open();
    SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
    socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
```

//  Till here the code creates the top 2 connections to port 52209 and 52210

```
    socketChannel.connect(address);
    socketChannel.register(incomingMessageSelector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
    socketChannel.register(incomingMessageSelector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
    socketChannel.register(incomingMessageSelector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

// Then it creates 2 connections to port 1001

```
    Thread.sleep(900000L);
}
```

I want to understand why it creates 4 connections, with the standard TCP blocking library it tends to create 2 connections.

I use JDK 1.7 and Windows 7.

In the image only the 4 highlighted connections are of interest which are created by the client.

One connection 1 entry marked with red is the server port.

PFA a image which shows these 4 connections.!

Well i acutally most puzzled about why

```
Selector incomingMessageSelector = Selector.open();
```

creates a connection on an dynamic port

[image]

Comment: That does sounds strange.  IMHO I find blocking NIO much simpler to work with, and faster if you have a small number of connections.

Comment: Ya it might be simpler from the API from, however i am more focused as to why 4 connections are being created at the TCP level, when only 1 connection is created from the code.

Comment: Can you include the entries for "port 50512 and 50513" They are not in your image.

Comment: I had updated the image and hence got different ports in the new image and forgot to update the question text accordingly, I have now updated the question also

Answer (score 1):

The image is very small but on closer investigation you have

- two Java processes
- the first process has a connection to itself. There is a connection for each end, port 52209 and 52210.
- it also has a connection from the second process on port 1001.
- the second process is the client you are running with one connection to port 1001

Comment: Yes you are correct. However i have closed all IDE's and such and running via notepad :) .. 1 java process is the server which is hosted using tool called socket test, the other java process is the code which i posted creating the client connection. When i shut down the client program I am left with 1 java process occupying the port 1001 (the server program), and there socket level connections are created by client program.

Comment: That all makes sense to me. Can you rephrase the problem given that there is only one connection for two entries in the table and the others on the server can be ignored?

Comment: Updated question to make it clearer. I am think to summarize its a  total of 5 java process entries out which 1 is server and 4 are client connections

Comment: @Sudarshan Which process id are you talking about because I can only see 3 entries on one process and 1 on the other.  The one with the connection to itself has nothing to do with your code.  This leave one entry for the client and one entry for the server.

Comment: I have three entries with process id 9464 is that ok ?, Using normal Java Socket API and creating a connection, I get only 1 entry ... I am trying to understand why NIO creates more than 1 socket connection and that too why does it use dynamic ports for the same

Answer (score 1):

The connection between 1001 and 52211 is being shown twice, once in each direction, as both ports are local.

A Selector may open another listening socket in case it has to handle sub-selectors so as not to exceed the maximum number of sockets per selector.

You shouldn't register OP_READ or OP_WRITE until after you've finished the OP_CONNECT pgphasr, when you should also deregister OP_CONNECT. Having all three of those registered at the same time is definitely wrong.

Comment: "A Selector may open another listening socket in case it has to handle sub-selectors so as not to exceed the maximum number of sockets per selector."  -- Can you please explain this to me in a little more detail ... or can you refer me some text which speaks about how the selectors concept affects the socket layer ...

Comment: The platform has a limit on the number of sockets that can be selected on at once. Java doesn't: it uses a scheme of sub-selectors which talk to the main selector via an extra socket. When a sub-selector goes ready it writes something to the socket so the main selector wakes up. This is an implementation feature, not documented anywhere I am aware of except the source code.

Comment: Does it mean that a selector could open multiple sockets, via its sub selectors ?

Comment: It will open as many sockets as there are subselectors, and they will show up twice in a `netstat`, once in each direction.

Comment: How many sub selectors will be created in this scenario ? I can see that each time  Selector incomingMessageSelector = Selector.open(); is being called it create a connection on a dynamic port why is that so ?

Comment: It depends entirely on how many SocketChannels you are selecting on. If it is less than (I think) 1024 on Windows, no sub-selectors are necessary.

Comment: Well i acutally most puzzled about why Selector incomingMessageSelector = Selector.open(); line of code alone , creates a connection on an dynamic port ...