# Why does opening a java nio selector result in a socket level connection being created on a dynamic port

Tags: java, sockets, io, nio

I am trying to understand how the Java NIO library works ...

I have written some code which just opens multiple selectors

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Selector incomingMessageSelector = Selector.open();
    Selector incomingMessageSelector1 = Selector.open();
    Selector incomingMessageSelector2 = Selector.open();               
    Thread.sleep(900000L);
}
```

Each time when i open a selector i can see connections being created at the socket level, so for example in this case 3 connections get created.

In the below image i have highligted those 3 connections being made to dynamic ports ...

This question is closely linked to the this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945394/java-nio-connection-is-creating-multiple-socket-level-connections-why)

[image]