# boost::asio::async_connect creates not only one TCP connection but two

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio, tcp

I have just realized looking through TCPView that one single TCP connection established using boost::asio creates two connections. One of them using local ports and a second one with the desired remote port. Why? Is this behaviour normal? Is there a way of creating just one?

This question was originally posted several years ago:

http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/ASIO-tcp-socket-async-connect-connections-count-tc3901601.html#none

but nobody replayed.

Edit:

I'm connecting to the port 8001 and this is what I see with netstat -nao:

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:10246        127.0.0.1:8001         ESTABLISHED     3252
TCP    127.0.0.1:10244        127.0.0.1:10245        ESTABLISHED     3252
TCP    127.0.0.1:10245        127.0.0.1:10244        ESTABLISHED     3252
```

Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I finally found a related question thanks to EJP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945394/java-nio-connection-is-creating-multiple-socket-level-connections-why

Answer (score 0):

This is two connections, not three. Check the port numbers. Evidently the library creates a connection to itself for some reason.

It would be interesting to know whether it happens again when you create a second connection.

Comment: Do you have an answer to my question?

Comment: Just checked with two connections but it seems that is not per connection. It creates an extra connection only if you create a second io_service _and_ a connection is established.

Comment: Well there's your answer. Each io_service creates a connection to itself on the first connection. Java NIO's Selector does a similar thing, to overcome a platform limitation. As it isn't an extra connection, or two, per connection, you don't really have a problem.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which is that platform limitation?